# Linking: making virtual address corresponding to file offset

Tags: c, windows, assembly, linker, exe

I'm having small problems with getting my system working, so I decided to ask question if is it possible to make virtual address corresponding to file offset. So if virtual address of my `.text` section is `0x1000`, I want linker to fill "padding" space to position with zeroes. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to rely on this behavior? That's not a good idea to start with, and second it's probably not even possible

Comment: I need some alignment and space there.

Comment: I doubt any existing linker would do it. But you can fix header and section sizes by yourself.

Comment: ...You just need to move sections and update file offsets in sections table.

Comment: Why not just ask for a static array of the correct size if you want such a thing? I don't even think I quite understand what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mentioning *your system*, so I assume that it's related to hobby OS development and that you *know* what you're trying to do and why.

If the image is a PE file, you can make the file alignment equal to the section alignment. In GNU ld you can do that by passing `--file-alignment 4096` (as the default section alignment is `4096` and can't be less, according to the PE specs) to the linker.

If you don't care about making a valid PE, `--section-alignment 512` (`/ALIGN:512` for the Microsoft linker) may work, too.